# ssh unable to connect with external ip (port 22 is open)

Tags: networking, ssh, ip

I want to reach my home computer from work computer.

I've already installed openssh-server. Status is:

```
dpkg -l openssh-server

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  openssh-server 1:6.2p2-6ubu amd64        secure shell (SSH) server, for se
```

I get my external IP Addres by going: 
 [YougetSignal](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)
I check my port 22 and it is **open**. Because I forwarded incoming call to internal ip address both with DMZ and PORT FORWARDING methods.

I check with internal ip:

```
ssh 192.168.1.2
asa@192.168.1.2's password: 
You have mail.
Last login: Tue Jan 28 21:38:06 2014 from localhost
```

**it works**

I check with external ip:

```
ssh XX.XXX.XX.XX
ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XX.XX port 22: Connection timed out
```

**it doesnt work.**

What is wrong?

Comment: When you test with external IP, was that from a machine in home network?

Comment: external ip was the ip of VDSL modem.

Comment: You can't use your public IP from inside network, you can only do that from outside, you tell a friend test it for you or use an external machine (ex VPS,...)

Comment: Try `nmap -p 22 yourexternalip` from work.  Some work firewalls may block outgoing 22, so you could also try moving your SSH port to 80 or 443 and trying to connect to it from your corporate network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, but many soho routers don't let you access the forwarded ports from the LAN interface.
You can ask a friend to connect to your pc. At least from my machine, I can connect your ip at this moment.

Comment: It's neither a feature or a bug. Most DSL/cable modem do not have loopback turned on. Unfortunately, they do not provide an easy way to turn it on and keep it on.

Comment: Ah, that's been the word I was searching for in my mind :) Thanks.